# How to git-revert only partially as in git-add -p?

Tags: git, revert, git-revert

I noticed the introduction of an error in a previous commit that also contains some otherwise correct changes (which, at that time, seemed related enough to put all into a single commit<sup>1</sup>). Now if I simply `git-revert` the commit, I also revert the good changes, so is there a way to choose which part to revert, maybe similar to the way `git-add -p` works?

<sub>1) also, I was fresh to git back then...</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git revert -n` and discard changes you don't need before committing?

Comment: ah, add `git reset HEAD` to that and then I can simply use `git add -p`. Thanks!